# If $A\cap B=\varnothing$, prove that $A\subset B'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A\cap B=\varnothing$, prove that $A\subset B'$?

Please help. I didn't get any idea regarding this matter.

Comment: You get intersection by `\cap` and the symbol for empty set is `\emptyset`. Also, what is $B^\prime$?

Comment: @martin $B'$ is the complement of $B$ consisting of all $x$ such that $x \notin B$.

Comment: Ok, thanks, that makes sense from the question. I think it should be defined regardless. It is not necessarily standard notation.

Comment: Mr Galois: Your name is a little bit pretentious, no ? Particularly if you ask such question !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$A\cap B=\emptyset \implies$  There are no common elements in $A$ and $B$.

$B'$ is a set which contains all and only those elements which aren't in $B$.

$\implies B' \cap B=\emptyset$

Therefore, if $A$ is a set whose all elements are different from $B$ it must have some or all of the elements from $B'$.

$\implies A \subset B'$

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* $A = (A \cap B) \cup (A \cap B')$

Comment: from what relationship did you get this?

Comment: @ÉvaristeGalois, from the definitions or from $A\cap (B\cup C)=(A\cap B)\cup (A\cap C)$, with $C=B'$.

Comment: @lab, which law is this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebra_of_sets#The_fundamental_laws_of_set_algebra

Answer (score 2):

Proof (by contradiction)

Assume that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. We want to show that $A\subset B$. Let $x\in A$. This is where we insert the idea of contradiction. Suppose  that $x\notin B'$. Then $x\in B$. This implies that $x\in A\cap B$, which means that $A\cap B\neq\emptyset$. This contradicts our assumption that $A\cap B=\emptyset$. Therefore, we cannot assumed that $x\notin B'$. In other words, we have to accept that $x\in B'$. Since $x$ was chosen arbitrarily, we conclude that for every $x\in A$, we have $x\in B'$. Thus, using the definition of a subset, we get $A\subset B'$.