# Prove that $A = B = C = D$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$A, B, C, D$ are sets, where $A \not = \emptyset$ and $B \not = \emptyset$. Equation $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A) = C \times D$ is true.

Prove that $A = B = C = D$.

I tried to find $A, B, C, D$ separately, but that didn't get me anywhere. Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am sure that this is correct:
$A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_i,\ldots\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_i,\ldots\}$. Then we have that $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)=\{(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_i,b_i),(b_1,a_1),\ldots\}$. In other words, the set $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$ contains pairs, where every element from $A$ and $B$ appears a first co-ordinate, but also as a second co-ordinate. 
Don't know how to continue though.

Answer (score 2):

Draw a diagram!

[image]

Here, the shaded area is the set $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A)$.  It should be fairly intuitive from looking at this why the shaded area can only be equal to $C\times D$ if $A=B=C=D$.  Now you need to translate that intuition into formal language.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

Consider the first coordinate of each of the items in $A \times B$; that set of first-coordinates is all of $A$.

What are all the first coordinates of all the items in $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A)$? (i.e., what is the set of first coordinates?)

(By "first coordinate" of an ordered pair $(x, y)$, I mean $x$, by the way).

What are the second coordinates of the items in the same set? What about those on the right-hand side?

Where did you use the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty?

Comment: Ok, so if $(A \times B) \cup (B \times A)$, then $\{(x, y)| (x,y) \in (A, B) \land (x,y) \in(B, A)\}$. Is that correct? So far I haven't put the given statement "$A$ and $B$ are nonempty" into use.

Comment: Its a union, not an intersection.  A correct rewording of the left hand side is $\left((A\times B)\cup (B\times A)\right)=\left\{(x,y)|\left(x\in A~\wedge y\in B\right)\vee \left(x\in B~\wedge~y\in A\right)\right\}$

Comment: Sorry, I just noticed that I wrote my wrong version here. We know that it is equivalent to $C \times D$, $\{(x,y)| x \in C \land y \in D\}$. How do I continue?

Comment: @JMoravitz Now I know that $(x \in A \land y \in B) \lor (x \in B \land y \in A) = x \in C \land y \in D$, but I feel like I'm not even close to proving the equivalence of $A, B, C$ and $D$.

Comment: I usually call them *abscissae* and *ordinates*, but that feels really weird outside the $xy$-plane, so I don’t know.

Comment: The question is asked was "What are all the first-coordinates of items in $A \times B$?" I'm going to answer that: that set of first-coordinates is exactly the set $A$. (And this claim uses the fact that $B$ is nonempty). Starting from that, can you answer the next question? What about the set of first coordinatesof things in $C \times D$? What does this tell you about $C$ and its relation to $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @JohnHughes But how can $B$ be nonempty, if it is given that $A$ and $B$ both are not nonempty?

Comment: @MathBear what?  "it is given that $A$ and $B$ both are not nonempty"... that is not at all what was said.  It was said that $A$ and $B$ both are not *empty*, i.e. $A$ and $B$ both *are* nonempty, i.e. $A\neq \emptyset$ and $B\neq \emptyset$, i.e. that both $A$ and $B$ have at least one element in each.

Comment: @JMoravitz I was told by my professor that when dealing with elementary set theory, it does not matter if you use $\emptyset$ or $\varnothing$, as they represent sets, not numbers. 
Similarly presented problem : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2207169/if-a-cap-b-varnothing-prove-that-a-subset-b?rq=1
But I edited the main problem to $\emptyset$

Comment: What does your most recent comment have to do with anything...  Although I prefer `\emptyset`, I never said that `\varnothing` was incorrect to use.  You very specifically asked "*How can $B$ be nonempty*" to which my response was *because the problem very specifically said that $A$ and $B$ are nonempty* and gave several different equivalent statements to the statement "$A$ and $B$ are nonempty."

Comment: Very much no.  You seem to have a great deal of misunderstandings surrounding what it means for a set to be empty and what the cartesian product of two sets represents.  $A\times B$ is *never* equal to $A$ for nonempty $A$.  Take for example $A\times B=\{a_1,a_2\}\times\{b\}$ compared to $A=\{a_1,a_2\}$.  The cartesian product $A\times B$ is the set of all possible pairs of elements where the left element comes from $A$ and the right element comes from $B$, in this example $A\times B=\{(a_1,b),(a_2,b)\}$.  This has pairs of elements.  $A$ however does not have the elements in pairs...

Comment: @JMoravitz Not really. 90% of the problems are caused by the language barrier, as I use google translate to translate every word you say. But thanks for the help, I have it correct now.

Comment: You should ask for help in your own language.  Google translate is bad.  Google translate can't convey meaning of sentences, only words.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at reasoning through it, with massive help from the other two answers. I'm not very strong with set-theory, so everyone please let me know if I've made any mistakes. Thanks.

$A=\{a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots,a_i,\ldots\}$ and $B=\{b_1,b_2,b_3,\ldots,b_i,\ldots\}$. Then we have that $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)=\{(a_1,b_1),\ldots,(a_i,b_i),(b_1,a_1),\ldots\}$. In other words, the set $(A\times B)\cup(B\times A)$ contains pairs, where every element from $A$ and $B$ appears a first co-ordinate, but also as a second co-ordinate. So if this set equals $C\times D$ then $C$ is the set of all first co-ordinates, namely $C=\{a_1,a_2,\ldots,b_1,\ldots\}=A\cup B$. But we could say the same about $D$, with the second co-ordinates, so $D=C=A\cup B$. So then $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)=C\times C$ but the set $C\times C$ would contain the pair $(a_1,a_1)$ and all other $(a_i,a_i)$. These pairs weren't in our original formulation of $(A\times B)\cup (B\times A)$ but they must have come from either $A\times B$ or $B\times A$. Without loss of generality, let's assume that $(a_i,a_i)\in A\times B$. This might suggest that there are no $a_i$ and that $A$ is empty. Can you finish it from here?

Answer (score 1):

Let $a \in A$ and $b \in B$.  Then $(a,b) \in A\times B \subset C\times D$.  So $(a,b) \in C\times D$ and $a \in C$ and $b\in D$ and $A\subset C$ and $B\subset D$.

And we also know $(b,a) \in B\times A \subset C\times D$ so $b \in C$ and $a \in D$ and so $B\subset C$ and $A\subset D$.

So $A\cup B \subseteq C$ and $A\cup B \subseteq D$.

Now suppose $A\cup B \subsetneq C$.

Let $c \in C\setminus (A\cup B)$ then $c \not\in A$ and $c\not \in B$ so $(c,a)\not \in A \times B$ nor $(c,a) \not \in B \times A$ so $(c,a) \not \in C\times D = (A\times B)\cup (B\times A)$.  But $a \in A \subset D$ so $(c,a) \in C\times D$.  That's a contradiction so $A\cup B \not \subsetneq C$ so $A\cup B = C$.

Similarly $A\cup B$ but the exact same argument must be equal to $D$.

So $C = D = A\cup B = B\cup A$.

Now we know that $a\in D = C = A\cup B$ so $(a,a) \in C \times D$.  So eithere $(a,a) \in A \times B$ and $a \in B$.  Or $(a,a) \in B\times A$ and $a \in B$.  So $a \in B$ and $A \subset B$.

Likewise $(b,b) \in C \times D$ so either $(b,b) \in A\times B$ or $(b,b) \in B\times A$.  either way $b \in A$ and $B \subset A$.

So $A = B$ and $C=D = A\cup B = A=B$.